# is node.js merely a functions file that has files in it? (read the question detail for more detail)

Tags: node.js, angular, bash

When I download [`node.js`](https://nodejs.org/) from the internet through [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell commands, am I merely downloading a "functions" folder that has many files in them, or am I downloading anything else besides that?

This question came from the shocking realization I got when I downloaded [AngularJS](https://angular.io/) framework and realized it was literally a one page document and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js contains a compiled executable that can load and run Javascript code.

This exposes quite a few built in functions that run compiled code within the executable, as well lots of other plain javascript in plain `*.js` files that make up the standard library.

But to run all that Node.js integrates the [V8 javascript engine](https://v8.dev/) which is written in C++ and then compiled for your operating system.

When you download Angular, it is meant to run in a browser. That browser provides the execution environment. So all Anglular must provide is it's own code, which you can then leverage for your own projects. Javascript libraries really are just Javascript.

Think of Node.js more like your web browser. It's a program that can execute Javascript, as well as provides the basic functionality you need to write Javascript programs.